# How to download file via a web service?

Tags: c#, web-services, asmx

How to download file via web service ?

I have Tried this but he application throws this error.

> Server cannot add headers after http headers have been sent.

```
    public static void StartDownload(string path, string attachmentName)
{
    try
    {
        string serverPath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath(path);
        WebClient req = new WebClient();
        HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
        response.Clear();
        response.ClearContent();
        response.ClearHeaders();
        response.Buffer = true;
        response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
        response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + attachmentName + "\"");

        byte[] data = req.DownloadData(serverPath);
        response.BinaryWrite(data);
        //response.End();
        HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To download the File Synchronously:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadFile("example.com/myfile.txt", @"c:\myfile.txt");
```

To download the File Asynchronously:

```
private void btnDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
  webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Completed);
  webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(ProgressChanged);
  webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("example.com/myfile.txt"), @"c:\myfile.txt");
}

private void ProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
  progressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}

private void Completed(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  MessageBox.Show("Download completed!");
}
```